# How to import object, push items into it and share/access updated object with/from other modules?

Tags: node.js

1. File `object.js`

```js
export default {
    data: function() {
        return [{
            cart: {
                restaurant_id: 'TestRest',
                customer_id: 'TestCust',
                customer_address_id: 'TestAddr',
                items: []
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

2. File `some_module.js` updates the `items`

```js
const cart = require('./object').default.data()[0].cart
...
cart.items.push({
    id: item_id,
    category_id: category,
    group_id: group_id
})
```

3. File `index.js`
   From this file how do I access the object updated by `some_module.js`? Currently, if I try to access the object required from `object.js`, I still get a fresh object with no `items` updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out you have to define it as global variable outside of any function scope:

```
import {items} from '../js/items.js' 

methods: {
    change_cart(()=>{
        items.push('')
    })
}
```